# Python 3.5.0 Time module: Finding the time in X hours

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, time

**Without the use of the Datetime** module but **with the use of the time** module, is there a way to obtain the current time, find out the time in X hours and then do something when that time is equal to the time now? It is preferable to be able to be done in Python 3.5.0 but it would be good to know how in both that and Python 2.7.13.

Comment: possible useful information: https://pymotw.com/3/time/ and [time.clock()](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.clock) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are allowed to use time module, and x is the number of hours,

```
import time
current_time = time.localtime()
future_time = time.localtime(time.time()+3600*x)

time.sleep(time.mktime(future_time) - time.mktime(current_time))

print "Time elapsed"
```